# pcl mouse event function “”viewer->addText“ code encounter error

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

When I debug the pcl documentation visualization mouse event function code as following shows:

```
viewer->registerMouseCallback(mouseEventOccurred, (void*)&viewer);

void mouseEventOccurred(const pcl::visualization::MouseEvent &event,void* viewer_void)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer = *static_cast<boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> *> (viewer_void);
    if (event.getButton() == pcl::visualization::MouseEvent::LeftButton &&
        event.getType() == pcl::visualization::MouseEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        std::cout << "Left mouse button released at position (" << event.getX() << ", " << event.getY() << ")" << std::endl;

        char str[512];
        sprintf(str, "text#%03d", text_id++);
        viewer->addText("clicked here", event.getX(), event.getY(), str);

    }
}
```

If I remove the code:

```
viewer->addText("clicked here", event.getX(), event.getY(), str);
```

It would work well, or I encountered an error:
[image]
[image]

I do not know how to solve this problem. Thanks!

After I clicked the Retry, the exception shows as:
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYRJj.png)

Comment: Do what your first error says. Press Retry to debug the application. Then change the "Stack Frame" on the debug toolbar to your code to see the line of your code that caused the problem.

Comment: Show the full stack trace at the moment when boost assertion failed. Probably you have some uninitialized ptr.

Comment: Maybe `viewer` is not correct.

Comment: According to the boost assertion, your `viewer` variable contains a nullpointer. How do you pass `viewer_void` to your callback?

Comment: Thanks, I have supplemented some debug results.